# What is the appropriate way of converting pandas Series object (Dataframe Column) to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Basically I have a dataframe:

[image]

as shown here which has 2 columns(Age, ImageData((200,200,3) 3D array of image pixels in float32)) lets say the name of the dataframe is **data**.

```
print(type(data["ImageData"]))
print(data["ImageData"].dtype)
print(data["ImageData"].shape)
print(data["ImageData"].ndim)

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
object
(1000,)
1
```

Converting Series to numpy array did not work. Though it changed the type to array it considered as whole array and put it as 1d

```
print(type(np.array(data["ImageData"])))
print(np.array(data["ImageData"]).dtype)
print(np.array(data["ImageData"]).shape)
print(np.array(data["ImageData"]).ndim)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
object
(1000,)
1
```

So Now what I wanted is to convert this Series Object to multidimentional array so that I can get something like but here I used list. This is was the result I was expecting to make series multidimensional this is the main goal of this post but not sure how to do without to_list().

```
print(type(np.array(data["ImageData"].to_list())))
print(np.array(data["ImageData"].to_list()).dtype)
print(np.array(data["ImageData"].to_list()).shape)
print(np.array(data["ImageData"].to_list()).ndim)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
float32
(1000, 200, 200, 3)
4
```

I have some questions here

1. Why Series object cannot be converted to array or multidimentional array without using the list?
2. Why series is stored as 1d in array when converted using `np.array()`?

Can anyone please explain to me I have started learning python recently and It would be really benificial if someone could point out my mistake it would would be really helpful in continuing my learning. Sorry if some of the terminology or explanation is not clear. I tried to look it on this platform there are lot of similar or same question as mine but I could not find in a bit detail so any references relatable will help thanks

Comment: Both dataframe and series (single column) have a `values` attrjbute or `to_numpy` method.  Those should be documented. If the series contains arrays (object dtype) the array will also be object dtype with array elements.  `np.stack` may be able to construct a numeric array from that.

Comment: `np.array(aSeries)` is the same as `aSeries.to_numpy()` or `aSeries.values`. The resulting array may actually be the array that `aSeries` uses internally (or a view or a copy).  Anyways there's minimal processing.  I suggested `np.stack`, though the `np.array(.....to_list())` approach is just as good (provided the component arrays all have the same shape).